# PHP MySQL dynamic search issue

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, random

I have a dynamic SQL search that im having a problem with on the 'mileage' down list option:

```
    <?php
include('connection.php');



if(isset($_POST['Make']))
{
    $makeSearch = $_POST['Make'];
    $modelSearch = $_POST['Model'];
    $colourSearch  = $_POST['Colour'];
    $townSearch = $_POST['Town'];
    $regionSearch = $_POST['Region'];
    $regiSearch = $_POST['Reg'];
    $maxSearch = $_POST['MaxPrice'];
    $minSearch = $_POST['MinPrice'];
    $maxMilSearch = $_POST['MaxMil'];

}
else
{

    $makeSearch = $_GET['Make'];
    $modelSearch = $_GET['Model'];
    $colourSearch  = $_GET['Colour'];
    $townSearch = $_GET['Town'];
    $regionSearch = $_GET['Region'];
    $regiSearch = $_GET['Reg'];
    $maxSearch = $_GET['MaxPrice'];
    $minSearch = $_GET['MinPrice'];
    $maxMilSearch = $_GET['MaxMil'];


}




if(!isset($_GET['pageNo']))
{
    $pageNo = 0;
}


else
{
    $pageNo = $_GET['pageNo'];
}

$noOfRecords = 4;
$startRecord = $pageNo * $noOfRecords;
$nextPage = $pageNo + 1;
$prevPage = $pageNo - 1;
$curpage = $pageNo + 1;




        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE 1=1";
    if($makeSearch !== "Select Make")
    {
        $sql2 .= " AND make = '$makeSearch'";
    }
    .....................
    if($maxMilSearch !== "Select Max Mileage")
    {
        $sql2 .= " AND miles <= '$maxMilSearch'";
    }

















        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE 1=1";
    if($makeSearch !== "Select Make")
    {
        $sql .= " AND make = '$makeSearch'";
    }
    .........................
    {
        $sql .= " AND miles <= '$maxMilSearch'";
    }

    $sql .= "LIMIT $startRecord, $noOfRecords";


    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2,$odbc) or die ("Can't run query1");
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$odbc) or die ("Can't run query2");

    echo"$sql";

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result2);


echo"$num_rows";

$last = ceil($num_rows/$noOfRecords);


if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    echo "No cars found";

}



else

{
    echo "<table border = 1>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->make;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->model;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->Reg;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->colour;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->miles;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->price;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->dealer;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->telephone;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->description;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->carIndex;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->region;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td>";
                echo$row->town;
            echo"</td>";
            echo"<td><a href='look.php?carIndex=$row->carIndex&Reg=$row->Reg&make=$row->make&model=$row->model&colour=$row->colour&price=$row->price&miles=$row->miles&dealer=$row->dealer&telephone=$row->telephone&description=$row->description&region=$row->region'>More Info</a></td>";





    echo"</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
echo"$curpage";
echo"$last";
if($pageNo >= 1)
{

        echo "<td><a href='search.php?pageNo=$prevPage&Make=$makeSearch&Model=$modelSearch&Reg=$regiSearch&MaxMil=$maxMilSearch&Colour=$colourSearch&Town=$townSearch&Region=$regionSearch&MaxPrice=$maxSearch&MinPrice=$minSearch'>Previous</a></td>";
}

if($pageNo < $last - 1)
{
        echo "<td><a href='search.php?pageNo=$nextPage&Make=$makeSearch&Model=$modelSearch&Reg=$regiSearch&MaxMil=$maxMilSearch&Colour=$colourSearch&Town=$townSearch&Region=$regionSearch&MaxPrice=$maxSearch&MinPrice=$minSearch'>Next</a></td>";
}       
    echo"</tr>";
    echo"</table>";


}
```

?>

The problem I'm having is the 'Mileage' input is as far as I can see, being ignored. If I enter (from my drop down list) for example 5000 miles to return all cars below and equal to this, its returning random results with any mileage. What I will say is that if I select for example a car make then select a mileage it will return the correct result.

Really not sure what im doing wrong here as all my other options work correctly.

Any help would be great!

Comment: echo the final query and post

Comment: Hi, Do you mean echo:  $result = mysql_query($sql,$odbc) or die ("Can't run query2"); i.e echo what '$result' is?

Comment: are you perhaps getting confused with the single vs double quotes?  Instead of placing the `$variables` inside a string try inserting them like this `$sql .= " AND miles <= '".$maxMilSearch."'";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echoing out the final resulting query will give you a hint if everything is in order.  Running it through PHPMYADMIN would also give you a good indication that your query is valid and returns the correct results.

This slightly different method of assembling the query might help you.  It also IMO makes it a little easier to read.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE ";
$whereClause = array();

if($makeSearch !== "Select Make"){
    $whereClause[] = "make = '$makeSearch'";
}

...

if($maxMilSearch !== "Select Max Mileage"){
    $whereClause[] = "miles <= '$maxMilSearch'";
}

$sql .= implode(" AND ",$whereClause) . "LIMIT $startRecord, $noOfRecords";

echo $sql;
exit();
```

That should print out the final query to the screen and thex exit.

I'm using the shorthand version of `array_push()` to add elements to the `$whereClause` array - `$whereClause[] = VALUE`.  The `[]` is like a push action; Adding an additional element to the end of the array.

The other useful function I've used is the `implode()` function.  This method takes an array and joins it together into one string using the given string to connect them.  It is really useful when assembling queries as you are doing here.

In addition to using it for the where clause you could use it for a list of values too -

```
$cowDetails = array(
 '1',
 '"Cow"',
 '"Moo"'
);
$insertSql = "INSERT INTO `zoo` ('id','name','sound')  
              VALUES  (".implode(',',$cowDetails).")";

echo $insertSql;
exit();
```

> ***Output*** :
>   `INSERT INTO`zoo`('id','name','sound') VALUES (1,"Cow","Moo")`

Once you have verified that the query is correct you can remove the `echo` and the `exit()` commands.

Comment: Thanks Lix, Heres my sql output SELECT * FROM cars WHERE 1=1 AND miles <= '2000' I just chose a random '2000' value. I also have another script for pagination (which is exactly the same which gave me the sql of SELECT * FROM cars WHERE 1=1 AND miles <= '2000' LIMIT 0

Comment: You should add that to your original post and delete this comment :)  Did my answer assist you?

Comment: Just to add I have ran this query in phpmyadmin SELECT * FROM cars WHERE 1=1 AND miles <= 2000 and it works fine so the problem is definitely in my script. I just haven't got a clue where!

Comment: Im going to try your method now Lix.

Comment: Tried your array method Lix and sadly its doing the same thing. Just seems to be the miles field it takes no notice of!

Comment: Why don't you shorten your post (like how I posted) and add some more of the code you are using - how exactly are you are executing the query and reading the results?

Comment: Ok Lix, as requested Ive posted the whole page of script. Just checked and rechecked the query's that are being echo'd on phpmyadmin and it works perfectly......The mileage is simply posted from a form on my homepage.

Comment: Sorted it! Ty for all your help Lix

Comment: @tou - why not formulate your findings to post as an answer here if you feel like it would benefit someone in the future.

Comment: Its almost embarrassing what the actual problem was. Basically I had the 'mile' table of the database set to varchar instead of int!

Comment: Oh - ok - no worries! Happens to the best of us!  Also make sure to sanitize any input you are getting from the `$_POST` variable - if you are expecting an `int` - then make sure what you have is an `int`.

Comment: Haha it had to be something silly as it all worked perfectly else where. Many thanks for your help though Lix! I will definitely do that, I have a SQL injection test on a login screen. Thanks again!